# How to set radio button value by query string value on page load using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to set radio button value by query string value **on page load** using AngularJS?

**My View Code**

Option One: This field can populate the "$scope.purpose" item in Controller, but doesn't select the radio button.

```
<input id="QueryStringLoanType" type="hidden" ng-model="data.purpose" ng-init="data.purpose = setLoanType()" />
```

Option Two: This field can populate the "$scope.data.purpose" item in Directive and selects the correct radio button, but I have to hard code value for it to work.

```
<input id="QueryStringLoanType" type="hidden" ng-model="data.purpose" ng-init="data.purpose = 'purchase'" />
```

**My Controller**

```
// Function: Set loan type
$scope.setLoanType = function () {
var queryStringLoanType = $location.search().loan_purpose;
$scope.purpose = queryStringLoanType;
if (queryStringLoanType == 'refi-loan') {
  $scope.purpose = "refinance";
}
if (queryStringLoanType == 'purchase-loan') {
  $scope.purpose = "purchase";
}
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
  <label class="btn btn-cta btn-lg btn-block">
    Refinance
    <input type="radio" name="QuestionButton" ui-sref="home.custname" ng-model="data.purpose" value="refinance" ng-change="processForm()" />
  </label>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
  <label class="btn btn-cta btn-lg btn-block">
    Purchase
    <input type="radio" name="QuestionButton" ui-sref="home.custname" ng-model="data.purpose" value="purchase" ng-change="processForm()" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: where is radio button html? what is the reason behind using hidden element?

Comment: I used the hidden input to store the value of the the query string item I'm trying to pass to Controller.

Comment: you can directly get that inside angular controller..no need of hidden variable.have you tried my answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution, but since both radio buttons affect the same model, the value is always set to "refinance" or whatever radio button shows last.

Comment: Oh..you're using different model for same radio then you should look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: All though @pankajparker answer didn't solve my issue, your answer did show me results and got me looking at things differently. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably your problem is with your radio buttons. You need to replace your `value` attribute with `ng-value` inside your radio element.

You might be declared radio button like this

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" ng-model="data.purpose" value="purchase"/>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" ng-model="data.purpose" value="refinance"/>
```

**Working Radio Button**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" ng-model="data.purpose" ng-value="purchase"/>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" ng-model="data.purpose" ng-value="refinance"/>
```

only changed `value` attribute to `ng-value`, Angular will manage the value binding of that scope variable.

From your question things are not clearing.

I'm hoping this could help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't post this question to answer it myself, but after playing around with different solutions, this is what worked for me.

My form is a shared form that works globally on my website, but failed when trying to load my partial form view into a new landing page I'm building. My problem was that I was unable to populate a directive model value in my angular form without hard-coding the value into an ng-int attribute. I'm sure there's a better way to solve this problem, so feel free to comment.

My solution was to wrap my partial view on my landing page with a tag of my directive's name.

For example:

```
<my-directive>

    <!-- Form Field -->
    <input />

    <!-- Form Field -->
    <input />

</my-directive>
```